# Bulk Edit Magento product attributes

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, ce-1.9.0.1

I would like to select and bulk edit attributes in magento 1.9. Like as we do in Products.
Scenario is to set selected attributes filterable at once.

Currently magento allows to go one by one on attribute manually  and edit and save.

Is there some free extension out, or please suggest me which class in mage need to be rewrite to support bulk edit of attributes.

Thanks

Comment: I may also write a php file to update the database table, but that is the last option beside some module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating a set-up script for this. One great plus side of using set-up scripts is it is harder to loose changes to multiple attributes.

```
$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'your_attribute', 'is_filterable', '1');
```

Comment: i'll try this for sure, and share the result +1 for u :-)

Comment: could you please provide more info on how to implement this snippet?